# How do I make the slider on a material-UI table longer?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm trying to make a table in material-UI, however the table slider does not go to the bottom.

Does anyone know how to make the slider for the table longer?

[image]

Comment: We need to see the code. Try to privide a stackblitz or live code with an example of your use case.

Comment: Nvm. It fixes when full screened